# Microsoft Teams Bot not sending message Edit/Delete events to bot messaging endpoint

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I set up an app using the App Studio within Teams and enabled a bot. 
I set up the Messaging endpoint for the bot and am able to receive `message` and `conversationUpdate` events from the Teams client.  This all works fine.

However, if I then edit a message in the Teams client, the messaging endpoint does not receive the text of the edited message at the messaging endpoint.
Similarly, if I delete a message, I do not receive an event indicating that a message has been deleted.

I'm wondering:

- Is this expected behavior?
- Is there somewhere these events have to be configured in order to receive them?
- Is there an alternate way to integrate with Teams/BotFramework in order to receive these events?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a known issue. We have a feature request created which is being worked on.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT is it possible to follow this feature request somewhere? I'd like to know whether it's MS Teams related or rather a missing feature of the Bot Framework. Thanks!